# What function should I use to loop through Node List in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
  navLinks.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.classList);
      return e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    });
  });
```

When I log out the classlist I get a list of all elements with the navLink class, not the clicked one. I have a feeling it's the for each function I am using. **How do I get the correct classist as in for the clicked link? , right now when I log out I get classes in all the navlink elements**

Comment: Your code should work fine. In what way is it not?

Comment: `e.target.classList` will be all the classes in the `.nav-link` that was clicked

Comment: It's intended that the `classList` contains all of the classes on the DOM element. See [the documentation of `Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: No, `console.log(e.target.classList);` logs the classlist of the clicked element ... If you want something different: What exactly do you want to be logged?

Comment: What you are mean with: "How to get correct classList" It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please explain your question a bit more?

Comment: @Nick i also thought it would but it doesnt

Comment: Well, please edit your question to make an example that demonstrates the problem you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

1. Use stopPropagation to prevent further propagation of events
2. classList is ArrayLike object, not actually an array. But it can be converted to Array.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases
    console.log('Array: ', Array.from(e.target.classList));
    console.log('ArrayLike: ', e.target.classList);
    return e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-link {
 width: 150px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link 1-item"></div>
<div class="nav-link 2-item"></div>
<div class="nav-link 3-item"></div>
<div class="nav-link 4-item"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't have anything to do with the question, and it is not even clear *what* the question is ...

Comment: `When I console.log out the classlist I get a list of all elements with the navLink class not the clicked one` what's unclear here? @derpirscher

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly That's not true. If you do `console.log(e.target.classList)` it logs the `classList` object of the clicked element and certainly not all elements which have a `nav-link` class ... Which can be seen in your own code. Or does it print `nav-link 4-item` anywhere if you click on the first item?

Comment: you're correct, and that's what OP is asking. so added stopPropagation and an example of ArrayLike, which OP might confuse with `...all elements with the navLink`

Comment: Well if that's the case, that the real point of your answer is the `stopPropagation` you should have mentioned that a bit more prominent in your answer. Currently the main aspect of your answer seems to be the distinction between `Array` and `ArrayLike` A *good*  answer also explains why it is the answer to the question.

Comment: Agree, should have mentioned explicitly

Comment: I don't think `e.stopPropagation()` is required here at all. I ran the snippet without it and it did not make the slightest difference. I rather believe that OP was confused by the output they received from `console.log(e.target.classList)` and therefore @MedetTleukabiluly's answer _has_ a point.